# Accidentally striking a ball with the cue after the first successful shot

Tags: rules, pool

In 8-Ball, after a break where no balls were sunk, the next player takes their turn. They
successfully sink a ball and the balls have stopped moving, but while moving away from the table for the next
shot, strike a ball with their cue. Is this foul considered part of the first
shot, and the table remains open? Or is it a foul for the next shot, and the
table is no longer open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under [World Pool-Billiard Association rules](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=116&pagetype=rules), a [shot](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=123&pagetype=rules#8.2) ends when the balls stop moving.  Therefore, the foul would be on the next shot.

This type of foul is called a [Touched Ball](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=121&pagetype=rules#6.6), and [in 8-Ball, it results](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=114&pagetype=rules#3.9) in the play passing to the opponent with the cue ball in hand.

Therefore, in this situation, I believe that the table would not be considered open anymore, and the player who made the break shot would get the cue ball in hand.